# how to run notification when the activity start and how to prevent it from starting again if activity is resume

Tags: android, notifications

I have a simple activity that call a notification but I have problem when I go back to the activity the notification runs again how can i prevent it from running again I have this code below

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
notification();

    }
public void notification(){
        // Invoking the default notification service
          NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);  

          mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message with explicit intent");
          mBuilder.setContentText("New message from javacodegeeks received");
          mBuilder.setTicker("Explicit: New Message Received!");
          mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.banner);

          // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives 
          mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);

          // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app 
          Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotesActivity.class);
          resultIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationIdOne);

          //This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of the app to Home page
          TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

          // Adds the back stack for the Intent
          stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotesActivity.class);

          // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
          stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
          PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
             stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT //can only be used once
             );
          // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
          mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

          myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

          // pass the Notification object to the system 
          myNotificationManager.notify(notificationIdOne, mBuilder.build());  

       }
}
```

Also I want idea on how to make multiple notification on both the same kind of event and different like for example I get 2 message from javacodegeeks then the number should increase and if I get message from different user then I get two different notification for two different message? This is the link where i got this tutorial

```
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/notifications/android-notifications-example/
```

Comment: at what point do you want it to run again? onCreate is only called one time when the activity is created, and shouldn't be called again unless the app crashed or the user closed the app.

Comment: @reidisaki please look at the code i see what you mean but why does the notification run again when i go back to the activity as you can see i put the notification in oncreate i want to run it again when the user open the app again and not on onresume

Comment: try commenting this out : stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);  and see if the notification gets run again. If this is your entire MainActivity class this looks ok.

Comment: @reidisaki yes this is my only code nothing else i will try and i will be back on you

Comment: @reidisaki i comment it but still the notification shows maybe bacause notification is loading when oncreate starts?any idea on it?

Comment: Can you try and put a log statement in OnCreate() and see if it gets called everytime you open the app? Don't click on the notification, simply open the app, tap home, then click on the app again. you should only see one log statement right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55597/discussion-between-reidisaki-and-hak-hak).

Comment: same as when i click on the app run the program go to other activity and go back to the main activity if it runs 2 log meaning it runs the oncreate again right? @reidisaki

Comment: unfortunately it did made another log when i go back to main activity meaning that the oncreate was called again and the log cat was posted again..